# Postgres crosstab (text, text) cascading within group

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

Table schema

```
DROP TABLE bla;
CREATE TABLE bla (id INTEGER, city INTEGER, year_ INTEGER, month_ INTEGER, val INTEGER);
```

Data

```
INSERT INTO bla VALUES(1, 1, 2017, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO bla VALUES(2, 1, 2017, 2, 20);
INSERT INTO bla VALUES(3, 1, 2017, 1, 15);
INSERT INTO bla VALUES(4, 1, 2017, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO bla VALUES(5, 2, 2017, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO bla VALUES(6, 2, 2017, 2, 15);
INSERT INTO bla VALUES(7, 1, 2018, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO bla VALUES(8, 1, 2018, 1, 10);
```

I am trying to aggregate them and put into a pivot table format, so that for each `(city, year_)` combination, I would have corresponding total `val`. Here is what I could figure out from online resources and official documentation.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab (
  'SELECT city, year_, month_, SUM(val) FROM bla GROUP BY 1, 2, 3 ORDER BY 1',
  'SELECT DISTINCT month_ FROM bla ORDER BY 1'
) AS final_table (
  city INTEGER,
  year_ INTEGER,
  january INTEGER,
  February INTEGER
);
```

This is the output I am getting right now.

[image]

Note how entry corresponding to group (`city` 1, `year_` 2018) is missing. I have not found any solution and think that maybe crosstab do not support such cascading structure.

I know that I can create a temporary variable (`city_year_`) to bypass this problem.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab (
  'SELECT CONCAT(city, year_)::text AS tag, month_, SUM(val) FROM bla GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1',
  'SELECT DISTINCT month_ FROM bla ORDER BY 1'
) AS final_table (
  tag text,
  january INTEGER,
  February INTEGER
);
```

Output here.

[image]

But `city` and `year_` in respective columns are my preferred format (which is visually more enriched and preserves original data - splitting `tag` variable into `city` and `year_` requires knowledge of how `tag` is defined).

Any work-around/help is well appreciated. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres's `crosstab()` expects the source query to be of a particular format.

> This statement [source sql] must return one row_name column, one category column, and one value column. It may also have one or more "extra" columns. The row_name column must be first. The category and value columns must be the last two columns, in that order. Any columns between row_name and category are treated as "extra". The "extra" columns are expected to be the same for all rows with the same row_name value.

The problem here is that you have `year_` and `month_` both as `row_name` columns while `crosstab()` allows only one `row_name` column. So, we have to use something else as a `row_name` column. Lets use this function `dense_rank()`

Try this.

```
SELECT year_, city, january, february FROM crosstab (
  'SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY year_, city)::int AS row_name, 
   year_, city , month_, SUM(val) FROM bla GROUP BY city, year_, month_ 
   ORDER BY 1',
   'SELECT DISTINCT month_ FROM bla ORDER BY 1'
) AS final_table (
  rowname integer, 
  year_ integer ,
  city integer,
  january INTEGER,
  february INTEGER
);
```

This produces the desired output:

```
-------------------------------------
| year_ | city | january | february |
-------------------------------------
| 2017  | 1    | 25      | 25       |
-------------------------------------
| 2017  | 2    | 10      | 15       |
-------------------------------------
| 2018  | 1    | 20      |          |
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. Missed this bit `The "extra" columns are expected to be the same for all rows with the same row_name value.` somehow. I did create a `tag` variable to bypass the problem. Totally forgot that I can still percolate original variables `city` and `year_` and write a `SELECT` on top.